# pip install dgl failed even with pip search and whl

Tags: pip, installation

I tried to install dgl(https://github.com/dmlc/dgl)

There were several ways to install it.(https://docs.dgl.ai/install/index.html#install-from-source)

1. pip
2. conda
3. from git source
4. from whl

and I failed with error message when I tried pip

```
$ pip install dgl-cu101
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement dgl-cu101 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for dgl-cu101
```

even pip search spot the package

```
$ pip search dgl
dgl (0.4.1)             - Deep Graph Library
dgl-bots.py (1.1.0)     - A python wrapper for https://bots.discord.gl
dgl-cu100 (0.4.1)       - Deep Graph Library
dgl-cu92 (0.4.1)        - Deep Graph Library
dgl-cu90 (0.4.1)        - Deep Graph Library
dgl-cu101 (0.4.1)       - Deep Graph Library
dgl-cu102 (0.5a200108)  - Deep Graph Library
```

conda also does not work

```
$ conda install -c dglteam dgl-cuda10.1    
Solving environment: failed

    PackagesNotFoundError:

 The following packages are not available from current channels:

      - dgl-cuda10.1

    Current channels:

      - https://conda.anaconda.org/dglteam/linux-ppc64le
      - https://conda.anaconda.org/dglteam/noarch
      - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-ppc64le
      - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
      - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/linux-ppc64le
      - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
      - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-ppc64le
      - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
      - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/linux-ppc64le
      - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/noarch
      - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-ppc64le
      - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch

    To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
    looking for, navigate to

        https://anaconda.org

    and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

install with source code is not available option because I am the remote client to the server and has no root access

install with whl seems nice but also occurred error.(https://pypi.org/project/dgl/#files)

```
$ pip install dgl_cu101-0.4.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
ERROR: dgl_cu101-0.4.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

I read almost every articles and most of them said it would be the environment problem,
but as far as I know, they match!

My env *server*

- CentOS 7
- python 3.7
- 64 bit
- minsky
- 4 GPUs
- designed for ML

My env *client*

- macos
- iterm2
- no root access
- access from different city

How can I solve this problem?
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conda channel

```
https://conda.anaconda.org/dglteam/linux-ppc64le
```

gives the clue. Your system seems to be based on a  `ppc64le` CPU, not the most frequently seen x86_64.

As you can see [On the conda page](https://anaconda.org/dglteam/dgl-cuda10.0), only `linux-64` (i.e. `x86_64`) is available. Same goes [for the pypi project](https://pypi.org/project/dgl/#files).

So your setup does not match.

> install with source code is not available option because I am the remote client to the server and has no root access

You should not need root access to compile the source code. The requirements [listed in the guide](https://docs.dgl.ai/install/index.html#install-from-source) are

```
gcc-c++ python3-devel make cmake
```

which, if not available yet could be installed using `conda`:

```
conda install -c conda-forge make cmake libgcc
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't noticed that. and your suggestion works perfect!!